# Problems form_for: RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Hello guys I have an error when I try to make a form_for in rails 5.1.

```
<%= form_for: @image do |f|%>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %> <br>

    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

It throws error:

```
ImagesController#edit is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

I had the same error when I was doing the new method and I solved it using:

```
url: {action: "create"}
```

But in this case is different and I cannot do `url: {action: "edit"}` 
This is my route. `http://localhost:3000/images/1/edit`
And this is my controller:

```
def edit
    @image = Image.find params[:id]     
end
```

Please help.

Comment: Yes I have it, the code from edit.html.erb is the first one shown. :(

Comment: Oh god I was searching by like an hour and you really did it, I'm so sorry, I have the edit.html.erb file outside the images folder, thankyou for your answer and your time.

Comment: Great! I made my comment an answer, if you wouldn't mind accepting it.

Comment: Why are you saying `form_for:`? Don't you want just `form_for`? i.e. call the `form_for` method rather than attempting to create a hash literal like `{ :form_for => @image }`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file at `views/images/edit.html.erb`? It's not necessarily an error. It's just telling you you haven't made a view for that action yet.